# Shapes in PowerPointApi BETA (PREVIEW ONLY) ] API not available

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins

I am trying to add a shape to a slide , but the error

TS2339: Property 'shapes' does not exist on type 'Slide'.

appears.

The beta office.js is linked in the taskpane.html
Office 365 64 Bit is uptodate in the beta channel on a Windows 10.

What am I missing?

Thank you very much for every hint.

[Screenshot taskpane.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5CZ5.png)
[Screenshot taskpane.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q20aU.png)

Comment: What is your Office version and build?

Comment: Hi Rick, thanks for taking the time.
I am currently working on Version 2111 Build 14623.20002 Click-toRun Beta Channel.
Best

Answer (score 0):

The error was related to TypeScript!
Creating a new project with yo and JavaScript did the trick.